# twitter cards and link twitter share link

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

I added several links to the page:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=some text&url=my_url">Twitter</a>
```

I want the same page will be added to post when I share using any of the links.
So I added:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="test">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="title">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="decription">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="inage_url">
```

Will photo be added to post when somebody will click tiwtter share link (after the twitter cards is approved)?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it works, but the photo is displayed only when View Summary link is clicked.

Comment: I put it on test server and send approval request to twitter. It seems it was approved suprisingly fast.

Answer (score 0):

I used twitter card in asp.net project
image dimension : 270x250

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

You can also verify your page on this link:  https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator